# Simple place to capture a change to bound XML in WPF

Tags: wpf, xml, mvvm, binding

I've got an XML structure bound to a WPF form, and have it all set up to commit the changes to a database at the press of a button.

I'm looking for a way of detecting that the user has changed anything in the model, to know to enable the "save" button, set the form as "dirty" etc.  I would prefer something on the data side, as the XAML view is cleanly bound and largely free of logic, and the ViewModel is fairly insubstantial as a result, so I'm wanting to indicate that the model is in a state that needs committing to the database.

One "hack" I've considered is at load time, capturing the XML, and then doing a simple compare to the DataContext's copy to determine whether the form is dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model like this:

```
public class XmlDataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private XmlDocument _XmlData;
    public XmlDocument XmlData
    {
        get { return _XmlData; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _XmlData)
            {
               if (_XmlData != null)
               {
                  // it's not likely you'll need this, but why take chances?
                  _XmlData.NodeChanged -= XmlData_NodeChanged;
               }
               _XmlData = value;
               _XmlData.NodeChanged += XmlData_NodeChanged;
               CanSave = false;
               Provider = new XmlDataProvider { Document = XmlData };
               OnPropertyChanged("Provider");
            }
        }
    }

    private void XmlData_NodeChanged(object sender, XmlNodeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CanSave = true;
    }

    public XmlDataProvider Provider { get; private set; }

    public RelayCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(x => Save(), x => CanSave);
        }
    }

    private bool CanSave { get; set; }

    private void Save() { }
}
```

Set the `DataContext` of your view to an instance of this object, and bind controls like this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Provider}">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=/Data/Field1}"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=/Data/Field2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Bind your button (or whatever) to `SaveCommand`.

When you set the `XmlData` property to an `XmlDocument` (which you can do before or after you bind to the `XmlDataViewModel`), it'll create a new `XmlDataProvider` and raise `PropertyChanged`, so the view's controls will all refresh and the data will get pushed out as you'd expect.  Changes to the bound controls will raise `NodeChanged`, which sets `CanSave`, which enables the `SaveCommand`.

If you subsequently set `XmlData` to a different `XmlDocument`, the bound controls will refresh and the `SaveCommand` will be disabled until the user changes data in the new `XmlDocument`.  And the previous `XmlDocument`'s `NodeChanged` event will be unregistered, so that the object can be disposed.

I gotta say, that's pretty sophisticated behavior for what is really very little code.  Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: Thanks @Robert - I've implemented this and it appears to be working well, although something in my XAML view must be changing my XML as it draws it as it fires the XMLNodeChanged event while it's drawing.

Comment: which I think was my issue with @Erno 's answer too.  I tried his approach with a similar result.

Comment: two edits to your code above, I had to add OnPropertyChanged("CanSave"); to the XmlData_NodeChanged event handler, so that the UI was notified that the CanSave had changed and knew to update, and of course I had to track down the implementation of RelayCommand (easy enough, but [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) if anyone needs.

Comment: finally worked out the issue.  NodeChanged was firing when a bound combobox was bound to a field that wasn't in the ItemSource.  Capturing and ignoring that condition within the eventhandler completed this solution, many thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement change notification on `CanSave`.    The `PropertyChanged` event isn't involved in enabling/disabling commands.  Look into `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` and `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

If the XML is contained in an XDocument you could use [the Changed event.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument_events.aspx)

The XmlDocument class has [a couple of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_events.aspx) that you could register for.

Comment: That looks like the sort of thing. Any idea when I attach that event, as currently can't seem to find a way of adding it post-binding, e.g. the the event fires multiple times while the form is initially loading.  I've tried .Loaded (it's a wpf treeview) but that didn't work.

Comment: By creating a specific call to load the XDocument and after that adding the eventhandlers instead of loading the xml right from the start/constructor. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No @Erno - I think I'm the one missing something.  Something in my view is firing an XMLNodeChanged event before it's finished drawing.  Can't work out how/why but must be a binding thing.